# CSS word-break: break-all; (only for long words)?

Tags: html, css

Based on:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Is there any way the example at:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-break

can give the following:

```
Thisissomeveryveryv
erylong word. This
text will break at
any character.
```

rather than:

```
Thisissomeveryveryv
erylong word. This te
xt will break at any ch
aracter.
```

?

In other words only break single long words that are wider than the container allows (e.g. 140px) else wrap them to another line if they overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`word-break: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) or [`overflow-wrap: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap). Here's how [MDN Web Docs describes `break-word`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break):

> To prevent overflow, normally unbreakable words may be broken at arbitrary points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in the line.

The page goes on to note that it is not supported in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

The [Caniuse reference for `word-break`](https://caniuse.com/#search=word-break) notes that `break-word` is unofficial and treated like `overflow-wrap: break-word;` (`overflow-wrap` is a synonym of `word-wrap`).

As it so happens, [`overflow-wrap`](https://caniuse.com/#search=overflow-wrap) seems to have pretty good support, so you'd probably be better off with that instead.

Comment: I tried clicking that forth example under CSS Demo: word-break at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break but it didn't break up that long word: Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotam. Update: Aha -- I see why - I used Firefox desktop.

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work on Firefox after setting max-width:92px; max-width:50px;  max-width:50px;  on 3 of the 4 columns in the div table.